# Removing auto-focus of titlebar

Tags: bug, status-completed

When I click *Ask Question* button, as the *Ask a Question* page is loading (which may take some time if the network is limited); I click the Question edit box and begin to type. Suddenly I look at the screen and I see half of what I've typed is in the Title edit box.

I think it is more reasonable if either typing is banned when loading is not complete or the auto-focus of title bar is removed.

Answer (score 3):

I remember this happening to me once too. Fixed in next build (`2014.5.5.*`), the title will auto-focus only if nothing is focused at the time the site fully loads.

Comment: btw, I think auto focus of question edit box is a better option at least in some sites. Because a better title may be chose after writing the question.